# How do I make this paragraph element move up?

Tags: html, css, margin, move

I have this all written out, and it all works perfectly, except for the final

element. I want to move it up into the center of the blue rectangle created by the div with class "defaultButtonStyle". I've tried using margin-top in the css to no avail. Do you have any other ideas?

```
<style>
body {background-color: #ebf0f3;}
.mainPicture img {height: 400px;
    width:600px; }
#gallery {position: relative; }
#gallery ul {list-style-type: none;
    width: 236px; 
    margin-left: -33px;
    margin-top: -15px; }
#gallery li { display: inline; 
     float: left;
     padding: 0px; }
#gallery img {border-style: solid: 10px; border-color: #ebf0f3; }
#gallery a { text-decoration: none;
             font-style: none;  
             color: #333; }
.popOut {cursor: default;
    list-style: none; }
.popOut a {cursor: default; }
.popOut a .preview {display: none; }
.popOut a:hover .preview {display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: -20px;
    left: -45px;
    z-index: 1; }
.popOut img {background: #ebf0f3;
    border-color: #ebf0f3;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px;
    color: inherit;
    vertical-align: center;
    width: 100px;
    height: 67px; }
.popOut li {background-color: none;
    border-color: #ebf0f3;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0px;
    color: inherit;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    margin: 3px;
    padding: 0px;
    position: relative; }
.popOut .preview {border-color: #000;
    width: 200px;
    height: 134px; }
.popOut p {text-align: center; }
.defaultButtonStyle {background: #ebf0f3;
    border-color: #ebf0f3;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    color: inherit;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 212px;
    height: 38px;
    margin-top: -43px;
    text-align: center; }
.defaultButtonStyle p .defaultImageText {top-margin: 100px; }
.popOut .center {align: center; }
#rightcol {margin-left: 237px;}
#rightcol .fixThisHeight {
    margin-top: 18px; }
</style>
<div id="container">
    <div class="mainPicture">
        <img alt="" id="JudgeBench" name="JudgeBench" src="http://PATH/files/pictures/JudgeBench.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div id="gallery">
        <ul class="popOut">
            <li>
                <a href="http://PATH/files/pictures/PodiumPlain3.html" target="AdditionalInfo" onClick="document.JudgeBench.src='http://PATH/files/pictures/PodiumPlain.jpg'">
                    <img alt="PodiumPlain" src="http://PATH/files/pictures/PodiumPlain.jpg" /><img alt="PodiumPlain" class="preview" src="http://PATH/files/pictures/PodiumPlain.jpg" />
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="http://PATH/files/pictures/PodiumRack4.html" onClick="document.JudgeBench.src='http://PATH/files/pictures/PodiumRack.jpg'" target="AdditionalInfo">
                    <img alt="PodiumRack" src="http://PATH/files/pictures/PodiumRack.jpg" /><img alt="PodiumRack" class="preview" src="http://PATH/files/pictures/PodiumRack.jpg" />
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="http://PATH/files/pictures/CounselTable3.html" onClick="document.JudgeBench.src='http://PATH/files/pictures/CounselTable.jpg'" target="AdditionalInfo">
                    <img alt="CounselTable" src="http://PATH/files/pictures/CounselTable.jpg" /><img alt="CounselTable" class="preview" src="http://PATH/files/pictures/CounselTable.jpg" />
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="http://PATH/files/pictures/PlasmaScreens3.html" onClick="document.JudgeBench.src='http://PATH/files/pictures/PlasmaScreens.jpg'" target="AdditionalInfo">
                    <img alt="PlasmaScreens" src="http://PATH/files/pictures/PlasmaScreens.jpg" /><img alt="PlasmaScreens" class="preview" src="http://PATH/files/pictures/PlasmaScreens.jpg" />
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="http://PATH/files/pictures/Stream_Projector3.html" onClick="document.JudgeBench.src='http://PATH/files/pictures/Stream_Projector.jpg'" target="AdditionalInfo">
                    <img alt="Stream_Projector" src="http://PATH/files/pictures/Stream_Projector.jpg" /><img alt="Stream_Projector" class="preview" src="http://PATH/files/pictures/Stream_Projector.jpg" />
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="http://PATH/files/pictures/AudioAids3.html" onClick="document.JudgeBench.src='http://PATH/files/pictures/AudioAids.jpg'" target="AdditionalInfo">
                    <img alt="AudioAids" src="http://PATH/files/pictures/AudioAids.jpg" /><img alt="AudioAids" class="preview" src="http://PATH/files/pictures/AudioAids.jpg" />
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div id="rightcol">
            <iframe width="360px" height="319px" class="fixThisHeight" id="AdditionalInfo" name="AdditionalInfo" src="http://PATH/files/pictures/JudgeBench2.html" title="Information About Courtroom Technology"></iframe>
        </div>
        <div id="defaultButtonDiv" class="defaultButtonStyle">
            <a href="http://PATH/files/pictures/JudgeBench2.html" onClick="document.JudgeBench.src='http://PATH/files/pictures/JudgeBench.jpg'" target="AdditionalInfo">
                <img alt="Default Image" class="DefaultImage" "http://PATH/files/pictures/DefaultImageFinal.jpg" />
                    <div id="MoveTheTextAround" class="MoveTheTextAround">
                        <p class="defaultImageText">Default Image</p>
                    </div>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<p>Just some text</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't, honestly, found a solution since I didn't quiet understand what element you want where.. and the images can't show since they are linked to an unknown source.

However, one reason why your margin was no go could be because it should not be

```
.defaultButtonStyle p .defaultImageText *{top-margin: 100px; }*
```

it should be

```
.defaultButtonStyle p .defaultImageText {margin-top: 100px; }
```

Give it a shot.

Comment: That would do it. I feel SUPER dumb, especially since I have properly formatted margins elsewhere.